# Stop debugging web application on IIS in VS2010 takes long

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, iis, detach

Whenever I stop debugging an ASP.NET IIS web application it seems to take very long before VS2010 becomes responsive again (2 or 3 minutes). This happens when I close Internet Explorer 9 (which stops the debugging session), stop debugging in VS (which closes the browser) or when I detach the debugger from the debugging menu (which leaves the browser open).

My CPU time for devenv.exe goes up to 25% during this period of time. I use the professional edition (no intellitrace). Starting without debugging performs ok when I close the browser. I have some add-ins and extensions installed like TestDriven.NET, Resharper, PowerCommands, Productivity Power Tools, VisualSVN,...

Any ideas what causes this annoying problem? Things I can try and disable?

Comment: You've got a quad-core (or dual+HT) CPU, right? So that 25% is really 100% of a single core? Just to clarify: this is debugging IIS, rather than Cassini (ASP.NET Web Server)?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice, quad core indeed with IIS 7 debugging on Windows 7...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to narrow it down by running Visual Studio in [safe mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/15/visual-studio-safe-mode-vstipenv0050.aspx). This will disable all 3rd-party extensions.

If the problem goes away, then it's a problem in one of your extensions. Try enabling them one at a time.

If the problem doesn't go away, then it's a problem with VS2010. File a bug on Connect. Also, try the pre-release VS2010 SP1 to see if it's already fixed.

Comment: Strange, safe mode worked smooth so i disabled all extensions and add-ins and tried as you said. Now everything is enabled again and the problem is gone...

Comment: It's possible that disabling an extension and re-enabling it caused it to discard cached metadata or something. The problem might come back. To be honest, love it as I do, my money's on ReSharper.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Maybe occasionally starting in /safemode may resolve this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to kill the (asp.net web server) tray icon near the clock? Generally the webserver causes Visual Studio to hang.

Comment: I'm not using the built-in web development server (aka WebDev.WebServer.exe) but IIS 7 for development and debugging. The reason is that I use a WCF "backend" which I also need to debug which can only happen if you have both "frontend" and "backend" in one process so I need IIS to share an application pool. Even if I call iisreset.exe the program still remains unresponsive. Also the High CPU time makes me believe that VS is actually doing something instead of waiting for a timeout. But that would likely be an overkill operation...